# In plugin combine a returned entry with custom table data

Tags: plugin-development, entrymodel

In a plugin I am returning entries from a section. Can I combine a returned entry from that section with data from a custom table into one model for output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your plugin supply a custom `MyPluginEntryModel` that extends Craft's `EntryModel` and merges in any custom attribute definitions from your custom table.

```
class MyPluginEntryModel extends EntryModel
{
   ....

    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::defineAttributes(), array(
            'customAttribute1' => AttributeType::Number,
            'customAttribute2' => AttributeType::String,
        ));
    }

   ....
}
```

Comment: Then how do I populate the model with both the entry and custom data?

Comment: I think this should work?
$outputModel = MyPluginEntryModel::populateModel($entry,$tablerecord);

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. My goal would be to return a model instead of an array of models.

Comment: You'll need to post the code you're using in the original question. Can't tell what's going on otherwise.

Comment: I got that to work just now. How do I return a model to the front end instead of an array of models?

Comment: `$arrayOfModels[0]`? Really hard to tell without your code and some context into what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Brad I guess I don't know the question to ask.

Comment: You and me both. :)